# Getting error in taquito nextjs project. [ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined]

Tags: taquito, beacon

I am working on a nextjs website for a tezos project.
In the local environment, it's working fine.
But I get an error while deploying it.

Error:

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at LocalStorage.<anonymous> (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-core/dist/cjs/storage/LocalStorage.js:89:43)
    at step (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-core/dist/cjs/storage/LocalStorage.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-core/dist/cjs/storage/LocalStorage.js:14:53)
    at /Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-core/dist/cjs/storage/LocalStorage.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-core/dist/cjs/storage/LocalStorage.js:4:12)
    at LocalStorage.set (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-core/dist/cjs/storage/LocalStorage.js:83:16)
    at DAppClient.<anonymous> (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/dist/cjs/dapp-client/DAppClient.js:635:64)
    at step (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/dist/cjs/dapp-client/DAppClient.js:59:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/dist/cjs/dapp-client/DAppClient.js:40:53)

> Build error occurred
Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:11661)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/Users/sanket/Squaꜩ/Project/Frontend/squatz/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12599)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  type: 'WorkerError'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

It's due to the Airgap package it seems.
I know that the error is because next uses server-side rendering and due to this error is occurring.

But I don't know how to fix it.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: localStorage doesn't exist on the server so need to assure that that part of the code can only run client side. Can you provide a repro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that in the nextjs application, the Airgap package code gets executed on the server side; hence, the localStorage was not accessible.

The solution here is to create an instance of the package on the client side.

You can find a complete solution to this by the Plenty Networks team here
https://github.com/Plenty-network/plenty-network-frontend/blob/main/src/common/walletconnect.ts

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure it only runs on browser/client side, there's a few posts about it on reddit/stackoverflow, you can check for window

```
const ISSERVER = typeof window === "undefined";

if(!ISSERVER) ....
```

or just make the component run client-side only with:

```
"use client";
```